# Break out string within element in 2D list, delimiter, python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I have a 2D array (list of lists) with this structure:

```
mylist = [['Bob','AA',3,'a string with a - convenient - delimiter'],
          ['Sally','BB',2,'a string with a - great - delimiter'],
          ['Jim','CC',2,],
          ['John','BB',2,'a string with a - silly - delimiter']]
```

As you can see, some rows have a long string at the end.  In this example Bob, Sally, and John have a string containing a pair of hyphens ' - '.  I would like to take the data within the hyphens and separate it out as its own element/column.  Appending at the right is fine.  Here is what I am shooting for:

```
newList = [['Bob','AA',3,'a string with a - convenient - delimiter', 'convenient'],
              ['Sally','BB',2,'a string with a - great - delimiter', 'great'],
              ['Jim','CC',2,],
              ['John','BB',2,'a string with a - silly - delimiter', 'silly']]
```

As you can see from this example, not every row will have the long string.  If it does exist, it will always be in the same column, in this case index[3].  How do I achieve my desired result in python?  Any help would be super.

EDIT:

This seems to work and required the least amount of code:

```
for i, val in enumerate(mylist):
    if len(val) > 3:
        array = val[3].split("-")
        val.insert(4,array[1].strip())
        print val
```

Another conditional could have been:

```
if '-' in val[3]:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [['Bob','AA',3,'a string with a - convenient - delimiter'],
          ['Sally','BB',2,'a string with a - great - delimiter'],
          ['Jim','CC',2,],
          ['John','BB',2,'a string with a - silly - delimiter']]

newlist=[]
for i in mylist:
    temp=[]
    for j in i:
        if '-' in str(j):
            temp.append(j)
            temp.append(j.split('-')[1].strip())
        else:
            temp.append(j)
    newlist.append(temp)
print newlist
#output 

[['Bob', 'AA', 3, 'a string with a - convenient - delimiter', 'convenient'],
 ['Sally', 'BB', 2, 'a string with a - great - delimiter', 'great'],
 ['Jim', 'CC', 2],
 ['John', 'BB', 2, 'a string with a - silly - delimiter', 'silly']]
```